# Passing data to view in node + express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using my node app to retrieve some data from an API and want to display that data in a view and allow the user to change it there. I'm calling the api and get a JSON response which I'd like to pass onto the view. Here's what I'm doing:

```
    var query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, ActivityDateTime, EndDateTime, WhatId, WhoId, Subject FROM Event WHERE OwnerId = \'' + user.userId + '\''  ;
    // execute the query and get response
    ...
    ...
    var ev = resp.records;
    res.render('index.html', {eventData : ev});
```

Problem being that when I then want to use the data in my view, I get an undefined error.

If I do:

```
    <div id='Subject'>#{eventData.Subject}</div>
```

I get a print-out of #{eventData.Subject}

Trying to use the data in JS returns an undefined error:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mydata = #{eventData};
    </script>
```

After some searching I found a post that suggested to stringify it first:

```
    var mydata = !{JSON.stringify(eventData)};
    console.log(mydata);
```

Here, I get a syntax error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id"

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic and can't for the life of me figure it out. I've found a lot of articles examples that explain how to do it in Jade, but I don't want to use Jade and using the recommendations from the articles results in "undefined" or "illegal character" errors.

I'm all out of ideas... help?
Tnx

Comment: what templating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using a custom handler: app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(str, options){
      return function(locals){
        return str;
      };
    }
  });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jonathan Ong's comment actually brought me onto the right track. Since I was using a customer handler for html, it wouldn't interpret any variables.

I switched to using ejs:

```
     // view engine ejs
     app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
     app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
```

and used the following placeholder:

```
    <%= eventData.Subject %>
```

This actually made my data show up. Thanks for all the comments and answers!
Michael

Comment: you should accept your answer, it'll make it helpful for people searching for similar problems.