# Express, how to pass variables from routes to JS file that is in the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express project that has client-side javascript in a separate file that generates a graph. I am trying to pass variables from the express routes to this javascript file so the graph can be drawn. 
I have tried the code below but I am getting following error.

> Error: Cannot find module 'js'

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../views/js/users_chart.js'), {
    'users': users
  });
});
```

Comment: do you have a `views/js/` folder?

Comment: You can't use `res.render()` for JS files, `res.render()` is meant to be used with a [View Engine](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki?_ga=1.12046708.1350534868.1471455458#template-engines).

Comment: @Craicerjack yes I have views/js/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving great help, found out a solution.

In order to have a javascript file in the client side that would receive the variable from the routes, I had to send the variable in JSON from the routes file to the javascript file the client side. I used XMLHttpRequest in order to receive the JSON in the javascript file of the client side.

Bellow is the code for users_graph.js which is the client side javascript file.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/users";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var users = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).users;   
        // do something with the users variable that was passed by the routes

    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be helpful for you to review the Express documentation for [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) and [serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

You can't render JS files.

It appears you want to serve your static `user_chart.js` with

```
/* server.js */
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
// serve your js statically
app.use('/js', path.join(__dirname, '../views/js/users_chart.js')
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    // pass variable to html page
    res.render('users.html', {
        'users': users
    });
});

// in users.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/users_chart.js">
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355701/passing-data-to-view-in-node-express) is probably helpful as well

Comment: `app.register` is not used in the latest versions of Express to register a new view engine. Instead, using `app.set('view engine', ejs);` would be one way or specifying a new engine using `app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);`. See [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: users_chart is not static, I am trying to pass users variable from the route to it and that what causes the problem.

Comment: @Ramez did you read the rest of the answer? From the link provided **res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])**
*Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.*

Comment: `users_chart` is static - Static files are typically files such as scripts, CSS files, images, etc... that aren't server-generated, but must be sent to the browser when requested.

Comment: This answer simply cause the error users is not defined. I believe because it is in separate javascript file not in the html rendered.