# How to display the response data in a input text field of a form in a html?

Tags: html, node.js

I am really new to node.js and do have a problem. I want to show the data from the logged in user in these inputfields.

I can access to the data of the logged in user by following code and can show it also on the console:

[Output on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPotx.png)

Here is the code on the server-side:

```
app.post('/aender', function (req, res) {

    res.send(req.session.username);
    res.send(req.session.name);
    res.send(req.session.email);

    var sql = "UPDATE user SET name ='" + [req.body.name] + "', username='" + [req.body.username] + "', email='" + [req.body.email] + "', password='" + [req.body.password] + "' WHERE user_ID='" + [req.session.user_id] + "'";

    if(req.body.password === req.body.password2) {
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Daten erfolgreich geaendert");
            res.redirect('/aender');
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/aender');
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML-Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<h2 class="page-header">Registrierung</h2>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="../app.js"></script>

<form id ="form1" action="/aender" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id ="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" id ="username">
        <script>
            displayUserData()
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id ="email" pattern="(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Zd!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|;:<>,./?]).{6,}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password2" pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Zd!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|;:<>,./?]).{6,}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Profil ändern</button>
</form>
<form id ="form2" action="/loeschen" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Konto löschen</button>
</form>
</html>
```

For example I do want to display the name, username and the e-mail of Max Mustermann, like that:

[Data on Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nor4R.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to view in node + express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355701/passing-data-to-view-in-node-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called interpolation and it is not directly possible in HTML. There are two possible options:

1. Create an API REST service omn the server side and do your call with ajax or jquery and then retrieve data (not the best option if you are not planning to have it for other purposes and not the best option in terms of security).
2. You can consider to switch to [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), which can be totally integrated with [nodejs](https://pugjs.org/api/express.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355701/passing-data-to-view-in-node-express) is a practical example of interpolation with jade, which is the predecessor of pug.

if you want to do this with ajax you've first to change server logic:

```
app.post('/aender', function (req, res) {

    var sql = "UPDATE user SET name ='" + [req.body.name] + "', username='" + [req.body.username] + "', email='" + [req.body.email] + "', password='" + [req.body.password] + "' WHERE user_ID='" + [req.session.user_id] + "'";

    if(req.body.password === req.body.password2) {
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Daten erfolgreich geaendert");
            res.json({username:req.session.username,name:req.session.name,email:req.session.email});
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/aender');
    }
});
```

(Please note that i have just corrected the function in order to do that, but your logic is still broken, there's no sense at all to pass the session parameters).

Then in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.post(/*hostname+*/ "/aender", function( data ) {
  console.log(data); // {username:req.session.username,name:req.session.name,email:req.session.email}
})
</script>
```

This is not a full complete script, but it is a good start for you to adapt.

Comment: But is there really no other possibility. Everything I really want to do is to show the username, name and mail of the logged in user like a preset in req.body.name, username etc. on page load. I have access to the data of the logged in user through res.send(req.session.username) and so on.

Comment: And do you know how to make that with ajax?? Have I to use res.send(req.session.username) there?

Comment: It is not easy because you've to change either the back-end tand the front end.

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer i have added some guidelines to help you, but since the complete answer requires a total change of your code i can't do more because i don't know the logic you want to implement. If it's ok for you mark the answer as correct please.